# How to enable silent evaluation in the XGBoost Java API?

Tags: java, evaluation, xgboost, silent

In the xgboost Java API, there is an option to the output with the parameter `('silent',1)`. This however does not seem to shut xgboost up about its evaluation of the data-sets; console messages appear, such as:

```
[16]    train-merror:0.004520
```

I know that in the Python API, it is possible to make evaluation silent with the parameter `verbose_eval=False` if you are calling the train function. I did not find an alternative for Java - does anyone know if there is such functionality?